# Can i play default button sound if system sound is OFF

Tags: android, button, system-sounds

I am getting the default button sound using the following code. But I want to play the default button sound to my button click. If the system sound is off.

I am using this code to get the default sound and play in my button on click.

view.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);